# Display different currency symbol in toshibha network printer

Tags: c#, sockets, printing, label, tcpclient

I am trying to print CPCL commands in toshiba printer using C# tcpclient socket programming.

This is my code

```
     System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
      client.Connect(ipAddress, port)
      StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream())
      string printtemplate="! 0 200 200 300 1

                            PAGE-WIDTH 396

                            T 4 1 10 80 £75

                            T 4 1 140 80 £75

                            T 4 1 280 80 £75

                            FORM

                            PRINT" ;
                            byte[] unicodeBytes =   Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(printtemplate);
                            byte[] win1252bytes =  Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), unicodeBytes);
                            writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                           string win1252String =  Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(win1252bytes);
                           writer.Write(win1252String);
                         writer.Flush();
                       writer.Close();
                     client.Close();
```

When I am trying to execute, it is printing u75 u75 u75 in toshiba printer.
Output should be £75 £75 £75
also it should support other country currency symbols like euro, doller and all.